# How to access a file created by a recipe in the next step when the file name is arbitrary

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that is something like this:

```
target:
         command_that_creates_a_file_with_arbitrary_filename
         i_want_to_something_with_the_newest_file_in_directory_x
```

doing `FILENAME=$(shell ls -1t directory_x |head -n 1)` will give me the filename of the previous round, as would inlined `$(shell ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use make functions to find the file.  But why do you want to?  You're already IN a shell, to execute the recipe.  Using the make `shell` function is just redundant.

```
target:
         command_that_creates_a_file_with_arbitrary_filename
         newfile=`ls -1t directory_x |head -n 1`; i_want_to_something_with $$newfile
```